# How do I represent a stance effectively

Tags: dnd-4e

Currently playing a game and we are going to be using [iplay4e](http://iplay4e.appspot.com/) for our combats. One of the characters involved in the game is a Scout who will almost always be in some stance or another. Stances often have a skill benefit as well as change AC or another defense.

Is there a way in iplay4e to represent a persistent effect that will change roll outcomes in an ongoing manner? The ability to add status effects exists, however there seems to be no way to meaningfully change stats/rolls due to the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit the DND4E file**

A counterinutitive point, but it is possible to add ad-hoc and custom weapons to the D&D 4e file, as well as hacking out .part files for CBLoader. By adding a custom weapon for: "Weapon+Stance" Then the impact of the stance can be pre-configured into your attack and damage rolls.

It's a fair bit of work, but it worked in the last play by wave we did with our Thief character. A proper solution is using cbloader to add stance modified weapons but that is significantly more work at the outset. You may also want to look into using change management software to auto-diff new dnd4e files due to levelup.b